# Can we specify degree of parallelism dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing

I have a select SQL query which use parallelism, something like this

```
INSERT/*+ APPEND PARALLEL (tst, 6) */ INTO test_table tst
                (
                    **************
                    **************
                    **************
                )
    SELECT /*+  PARALLEL (a, 6) */ DISTINCT 
                    **************
                    **************
                    **************
         FROM src_table a;
```

As you can see here, i have hard-coded the degree but, i don't want to do that, since the number of CPUs are not same across all the DB where this code is executed.

`My requirement:` I need to query `V$PARAMETER` for the available CPU count and use the value as `result-2` in my query. Something like this...

```
DECLARE
   degree        varchar2(1);
BEGIN
select value-2 INTO degree from v$parameter where name='cpu_count';

            INSERT/*+ APPEND PARALLEL (tst, degree) */ INTO test_table tst
            (
                **************
                **************
                **************
            )
SELECT /*+  PARALLEL (a, degree) */ DISTINCT 
                **************
                **************
                **************
     FROM src_table a;
END;
```

But, it is not working as i expected it to be and i see 32 parallel threads, irrespective of the available CPUs. Is this a right way to do? If not, is there any other solution for my requirement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vivek,

You could use dynamic SQL to build up your INSERT statement within a PL/SQL function or procedure. That way you could utilise the variable "degree" that you have already retrieved.

Something like:

```
DECLARE
   degree varchar2(1); 
BEGIN 
   select value-2 
     INTO degree 
     from v$parameter
    where name='cpu_count';              

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL (tst, '||degree||') */ '||
                     '  INTO test_table tst ( '||
                     '       **************  '||
                     '       **************  '||
                     '       **************  '||
                     '  ) '||
                     'SELECT /*+  PARALLEL (a, '||degree||') */ '||
                     '       DISTINCT '||
                     '       ************** '||
                     '       ************** '||
                     '       ************** '||
                     '  FROM src_table a');
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use oracle to automatically determine the parallelism?

Comment: How to do that? By using 'default'? If yes, wont this use all the available cpus?

Comment: @Vivek `default` is something else. Oracle can determine DOP dynamically when you set `parallel_degree_policy` parameter to `AUTO`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not force the degree for the session with:

```
alter session force parallel dml parallel <dop>;
alter session force parallel query parallel <dop>;
```

Without hinting you can fine granular define the degree you like.