# Oracle send degree of parallelism dynamically for Select query without PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a way to send degree of parallelism in a select statement without using PL/SQL procedure or function.

for example

```
select 
      /* FULL(t1) PARALLEL(t1,degree) */ count(*) 
from 
      table_1 t1 
where 
      t1.column1 eq 'xx' or t2.column2 eq 'xx';
```

is there a way to pass value to "degree" using subqueries?

Comment: did you see this? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160417/can-we-specify-degree-of-parallelism-dynamically)

Comment: And be aware that Oracle does a pretty good job at parallel processing, if statistics and parameters are correct.  And if you try to override it like you plan, you could adversely affect other queries running at the same time as yours.  Don't ask how I know that!

Comment: Thanks for both of you. @MarkStewart Yes I will plan the degree of parallelism which doesn't affect other queries.

Comment: @praveen- Yes, I had a viewed this page already where I could see degree of parallelism was parameterised using PL/SQL however my requirement is to make the degree of parallelism from value from another table using nested SQL queries. Is this possible?